# Python pd.DataFrame return Value Error : Array must be in same range

Tags: python, pandas

```
    list1 = ['Name','Class','ID','Phone','address','height','weight','number','Father','Mother','Sibling','Sibling2',
   'Sibling3','Email']
    list2[0] = [' Jason  4B                                 KB123  9999   US  150 113 6 Paul    Mary                                                              Andy                                                              Charles                                                               - a@xx.com ',
   ' Annie  4C                                 KB345  9991   US  163 119 2 Chen    White                                                              Bob                                                              Cyrus                                                               Ken b@xx.com ',
...
...
```

Since I crawl the data online and I used .remove to remove some `\n` between the text, so the list is messed up, but I am sure if putting `list1` on excel row1, the number of keys in `list2` can match the above, as there is a "-" if the student dont hv 3 siblings.

How can I use panda to sort these raw list and send to csv? Thank you very much.

for more information
I have tried to use `list2[0]` to check the elements, it returns

`' Jason  4B                                 KB123  9999   US  150 113 6 Paul    Mary                                                              Andy                                                              Charles                                                               - a@xx.com '`

and I have tried to use `list2[0] = [x.strip('') for x in list2[0]]`

and when I call the list2[0], it will show

`['Jason', '', '4B', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ...`

already can't find a way to fix this. Could someone please help

Comment: OS is for getting help with code.
post a code that you tried

Comment: and I have tried to use
test = {'list1': list1, 'list2': list2}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test, orient='index')
df.transpose()

but the table be like
row1 = all list1 items
row2 = all list2 items...

Comment: @gtomer which part of code you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use a regex to tidy up list 2

```
import pandas as pd
import re

list1 = ['Name','Class','ID','Phone','address','height','weight','number','Father','Mother','Sibling','Sibling2',
   'Sibling3','Email']
list2 = [' Jason  4B                                 KB123  9999   US  150 113 6 Paul    Mary                                                              Andy                                                              Charles                                                               - a@xx.com ',
   ' Annie  4C                                 KB345  9991   US  163 119 2 Chen    White                                                              Bob                                                              Cyrus                                                               Ken b@xx.com ']

df = pd.DataFrame([re.findall(r"[\S]+", item) for item in list2])
df
```

[image: out]

Then add list1 as columns

```
df.columns = list1
df
```

[image: out]

Comment: thanks for your help, sorry that my question isn't good enough
the upper should be list2[0] not the whole list2, so when I used your way it show error.
but i used `df = pd.DataFrame([re.sub(r'\s+',' ', item) for item in list2])` it worked.
but now I cant insert a column, it say Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 14 elements

Comment: Your regex function (re.sub(r'\s+',' ', item))  takes a string and substitutes substrings consisting of any number of whitespace characters with a single whitespace character and returns a STRING. That's why your axis only had 1 element, because your list comprehension returned two strings.

My regex function (re.findall(r"[\S]+", item)) -note the capital 'S'- returns a LIST of any substrings it finds consisting of NON-whitespace characters. My list comprehension returned two lists.

Comment: but I tried to use your way, the df returns
`0 None
1 1
2 None
3 None
4 4
... ...
272 3
273 7
274 None
275 6
276 None
277 rows × 1 columns`

Comment: Did you copy my list comprehension but swap the 'list' for 'list[0]'?   i.e did you use "pd.Dataframe([(re.findall(r"[\S]+", item) for item in list2[0]])"? That won't work. Python is trying to break up the string (list2[0]) as part of the list comprehension instead of applying the regex function to it. Try just "pd.DataFrame(re.findall(r"[\S]+", list2[0])"

Comment: I see. it works but it loop twice, so their are 2 Jason in df
and I have one more question, 
list2[0] = `list2[0] = [' Jason  4B                                 KB(123)  9999   US  150 113 6 Paul    Mary                                                              Andy                                                              Charles                                                               - a@xx.com '`
Can I split KB and 123 to be 2 elements??
thank you very much

Comment: I'm guessing you're probably still writing a list comprehension (i.e. [(re.findall(r"[\S]+", list2[0]) for item in list2]) so it's producing the results of the regex function (which is what you want) twice (once for each item in list2). To split the KB and 123 you'll have to play around with the regex function. comments aren't the best place for sharing code but try pd.DataFrame([[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r"([A-Z,a-z]{2,}|\d{2,}|\d\S|(\d(?!= )))", list2[0])]]). Although it's probably easier to just split the id column. have a look through the pandas.series.str docs.

Comment: Also this would be a lot easier if you posted new questions and linked them rather than us trying to share code in the comments.

Comment: I have tried your way, its works, for the duplicate issue I found out just because my previous for loop code is incorrect. and for the split the bracket, I may try to find out on my own first, Thanks again.
Since I can only ask 1q per day. please allow me ask  you one more question here first
`mylist = [('1','2','3'),('4','5','6'),('7','8','9')]
 test_list=['5','5']`
how can I insert test_list to every elem on mylist
output like
`mylist = [('5','5','1','2','3'),('5','5','4','5','6'),('5','5','7','8','9')]`
thanks

Comment: mylist = [tuple(test_list)+item for item in mylist].

If my answers have been helpful, could you do me a favour and upvote/ accept them please? I'm trying to get enough rep to leave comments.

Comment: I have accepted the answer and tried to upvote but it say not enough 15 reputation, sorry about that and thanks for your every reply

Comment: for the above insert list question, how can it change to insert between the elements/end of the elements?

Comment: Tuples are not mutable. You can convert the tuple into a list and use slicing - new_item=list(item); new_item[position:position] = test_list - or you can convert the list to a tuple concatenate slices of the old tuple and list into a new tuple - new_tuple=old_tuple[:2] + tuple(test_list) + old_tuple[2:].

Comment: I have ask a new question, could you please take a look?